# Sequelize association for already created tables not working

Tags: node.js

I am using `PostgreSQL` database and I have two already created tables 
    `user_details` and `location_details`.

The `user_details` table has `location_id` as a foreign key, which references `id` as a primary key in `location_details` table.

Now I am using sequelize with Node.js to associate these two tables so that by `location_id`, and I can fetch the data from `user_details`.

The models for both tables are defined inside models folder.

I have written sequelize associations as

```
models.user_details.belongsTo(models.location_details);
models.location_details.hasMany(models.user_details);
```

now i am using

```
     location_details.findAll({
         where:{id:1},
         include:{
          model:model.user_details
          }
      }
      ).then(function(user){
         res.json({Users:user});
       });
```

Now when I run my server and enter the URL in the browser, it gives me the error

> column location_details_id does not exists.

But now if I edit `user_details` table and change the column name from `location_id` to `location_details_id`, then also it gives me the error

> location_detail_id does not exists.

what to do please suggest.....

Comment: Please edit to use proper Markdown formatting.  See [How to Format my Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).  As is this is basically unreadable.

Comment: Basically formatting.

Comment: I think your mistake is in your models.